# How do I judge the accuracy of a model with 3 variables?

Tags: statistics, regression, mathematical-modeling, regression-analysis

For my high-school maths exploration, I have chosen to simulate heat flow in a one-dimensional rod using GNU Octave. I will then solve the heat equation and judge the accuracy of the heat equation in modelling the data.

For judging the accuracy of the model, I was thinking about using RMSE, but I can't find any formulae which work for three variables (temperature, time, length). Are there any other formulae of RMSE that can be suited to this purpose?

Alternatively, are there better statistical analysis tools that will help me judge the accuracy of the model?

Comment: If you solve it using an iterative method, then your error measure is simply a tolerance between previous and new estimate. And you solve it as long until the error is below desired.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? @mavavilj

Comment: Well e.g. with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method#Explicit_method you get convergent solutions $u_j^{n+1}$ which all become nearer and nearer the solution. Then you simply measure $|u_j^{n+1}-u_j^{n}|<tol$, where $tol$ is some small number, e.g. 0.01. And stop solving, when you reach solutions that are below the $tol$.

Comment: Or calculate the percentage of change of the new calculation of point-2 reletive to the previous calculation and use a % error tolerance to halt calculation. When the % error for new point 2 AND new point 3 AND new point 4 are below the threshold then stop.

Answer (score 0):

As heat is continually applied to the rod the temperature will continue to rise if there are no other losses.

I recommend you simulate a rod placed between two temperature sources and calculate the temperature distribution within the rod.

For example, if one end of the rod is subjected to 5-C and the other end of the rod is subjected to 125-C. Then you can simulate the temperature of discrete points along the rod.

This can be done by hand.

Let's say there are five evenly distributed points along the rod. $Point_1$ is at 5-C and $Point_5$ is at 125-C.

Thus:
$$Point_1 = 5$$
$$Point_2 = (Point_1 + Point_3) / 2$$
$$Point_3 = (Point_2 + Point_4) / 2$$
$$Point_4 = (Point_3 + Point_5) / 2$$
$$Point_5 = 125$$

Assume $0$ at $Point_2$, $Point_3$, and $Point_4$.

This is solved iteratively by solving for $Point_2$ (which will then be 2.5-C). Then solve for $Point_3$ (which will then be 1.25-C). Then solve for $Point_4$ (which will then be 63.125-C).

Then repeat the process until the values don't change anymore. (In complex calculations the iteration is often stopped when the changes for each calculation fall within a minimum level of acceptable error. Like, 2% of the previous calculation (your choice).)

A programmable calculator does this easily and can present the results continually.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I was going to follow a similar method, and then make the number of points tend to infinity to come up with the heat equation.

Sadly, this does not answer my actual question: how do I judge the accuracy of the model? Is it possible using RMSE?

Comment: Is RSME Root Mean Square? To judge the solution, you can gage the change in the solution through each calculation cycle (the ammount of change in each answer). I am not familiar with RSME, but you can compare your simulation with other simulation packages. caelinux.com is a free 4GB Linux download used for Computer Assisted Engineering. With the problem with this level of complexity, eventually all simulation packages will come up the same answer.